# Creating React Native App with Medusa.js - Cannot create admin due to module error

Tags: ios, postgresql, react-native, e-commerce, medusa

[application error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8YLQ.png)

Hi there.  I'm trying to figure out why my admin panel is not working with medusa.js for this e-commerce app tutorial I am following. Please see the link to tutorial below:

[link to tutorial](https://medusajs.com/blog/creating-react-native-ecommerce-app-with-medusa/)

I am able to build the webstore `my-medusa-store` fine and seed a postgres database just fine, I am able to get the program up and running with expo and can see the app in simulator and it looks like it should... but when I follow the part of the instructions on how to set up the admin panel to make changes to the app, it gives me error when I go to localhost:7000

`Unexpected Application Error! The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/medusa-react.js?v=455fafb5' does not provide an export named 'useAdminAddLocationToSalesChannel' SyntaxError: The requested module /node_modules/vite/deps/medusa-react.js?v=455fafb5' does not provide an export named useAdminAddLocationToSalesChannel'`

This seems like something that is missing with the module itself?
This is the repo on github for the admin panel. it says it has been archived and is read only, do you think something just became broken with it?

https://github.com/medusajs/admin

I'm not sure what I can do to get past this error.

I tried following the tutorial precisely, and even trashed everything and started from scratch a couple times and get the same result every time.

I was expecting an admin panel page to show up that I could log into and make changes to the app database.